# How to extract data from a pdf file using JPedal?

Tags: java, jpedal

Actually I am attempting to extract the data from a PDF file but I didn't find any example in the internet  and I am asking if there is any possibility that I can use the JPedal library to open to read the data from a PDF file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) from Apache.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with JPedal, but I write lots of code that generates and processes pdf files. I use [IText](http://itextpdf.com/) and highly recommend it. If you have a specific question on how to process a pdf file, let me know.